# Docker in docker volume mount doesn't work

Tags: docker, jenkinsfile, volume

I have the below command in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
docker run --rm -v "${WORKSPACE}":/var/cache/de --entrypoint=/usr/local/bin/pytest ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION} -m "not require_dss" -s -v --cov-report term --cov=app_dss_bundle --junitxml=/var/cache/de/rtest.xml tests

ls -l
```

I'm running inside docker slave, so it means its docker inside docker. I can't see the `rtest.xml` in the `WORKSPACE` afterward (it works for me in my private linux docker env). I already tried to run the suggestion of `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` but it didn't help. any other idea?

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes in shell meant to leave the enclosed string 'as is'. That is the variable inside single quotes isn't going to be evaluated. Try changing `'${WORKSPACE}'` for `"${WORKSPACE}"`.

Comment: I tried all the options, it didn't help